# C# Linq Unable to create a constant value of type 'System.Object'. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, lambda

I know that there're some similar questions to this one, but I'm not being able to fix my issue.

I have the following method:

```
public IDictionary<string, int> CountXXX(Expression<Func<MessageStatus, bool>> whereFilter = null)
        {
            try
            {
                var trackingOpens = whereFilter != null ? _context.MessageStatus.Where(whereFilter).Join(_context.TrackingOpens, x => x.MessageId, g => g.MessageId, (x, g) => x) : 
                  _context.MessageStatus.Join(_context.TrackingOpens, x => x.MessageId, g => g.MessageId, (x, g) => x);

                return trackingOpens
                    .GroupBy(x => x.VariationId)
                    .Select(g => new { Variation = g.Key.ToString(), Count = g.Count() })
                    .ToDictionary(x => x.Variation, x => x.Count);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                throw new Exception($"There's been an error trying to count the tracking opens from the database. Details: {e.Message}", e);
            }
        }
```

I have the class MessageStatus with `VariationId` property, I need to group them and count for each one. The problem is that I need to Join with `TrackingOpens` on `MessageId`. The `Linq`statement here is returning the exception mentioned on the title.

The `whereFilter` parameter is just another Linq statement that goes inside the `.where` clause.

`TrackingOpens` does not have the field `VariationId` and I cannot add it to that model

Can anyone help me fix this Linq statement?

Comment: What are the types of all of those properties?  LINQ to Entities can only work with database compatible types.

Comment: They are all compatible types

Comment: What is the expression being passed into the whereFilter?

Comment: this one `o => o.EventId.Equals(eventId) && o.ExperimentId.Equals(experimentId) && o.BatchJobId.Equals(Guid.Empty)`

Comment: Im seing that the problem is on that parameter is passing the data like: 

`{o => ((o.EventId.Equals(value(Microsoft.AEO.Services.Tracking.TrackingService+<>c__DisplayClass14_0).eventId) AndAlso o.ExperimentId.Equals(value(Microsoft.AEO.Services.Tracking.TrackingService+<>c__DisplayClass14_0).experimentId)) AndAlso o.BatchJobId.Equals(Convert(Guid.Empty)))}`

not sure how to fix that